# How to deploy on a remote Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10

There is a project that we have to deploy on a remote Windows 10 machine (no AWS, no Azure) and that's a requirement.

- Front-end is Angular 10
- Back-end is ASP.NET Core 3.1

We will use Docker and Docker Compose for compatibility. The question is how do we build both projects front-end and back-end on the remote machine (Windows 10 2004)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link: https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/
Hope it would be helpful